# brasero.toc.bin is very big -- why?

Tags: files, size

I have a file in my home directory: brasero.toc.bin, which ls gives as:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Harry Harry 633M 2013-09-26 15:53 brasero.toc.bin
```

in fact it is the second largest file listed, only sdc at 1.9G is bigger. My question is, please, what is it, why is it so big, does it matter, and should I do anything abut it?

Comment: This question is really hard to answer. Lots of things could have caused this file to appear, and we can only guess at them. It's a bit like asking why there's a big box in my living room. I mean, I can't remember it being put there... what's inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Questions: What is it, why is it so big, does it matter...

This file was put here by the application [Brasero](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Brasero) when you either attempted or successfully copied a CD. This is the contents of a CD as a single sourced file. As to what's inside it? Only you can tell us that, here's how, though.

#### Peeking inside

That's the contents of a CD image. You can use a tool such as `bchunk` to convert to an ISO file if you want.

```
$ bchunk image.bin image.cue image.iso
```

Then mount it using loopback to see what it is:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 image.iso /mnt/image
```

If you're missing the `.cue` file you can recreate it from the `.bin` file.

```
$ cdrdao read-cd --datafile image.bin --driver generic-mmc:0x20000 \
         --device /dev/cdrom --read-raw image.toc
$ toc2cue image.toc image.cue
```

Most of these tools are standard tooling which is often installed by default. If not you may need to install them using your system's package manager (APT/YUM/etc.).

**NOTE:** You can also go the other way and use `iso2bin` to convert an ISO to BIN file.

#### References

- [HowTo: Mount Bin/Cue files in Linux](http://goinggnu.wordpress.com/2007/05/08/howto-mount-bincue-files-in-linux/)
- [How to convert .bin to iso image, whithout having .cue file in Linux](http://extremefx.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/how-to-convert-bin-to-iso-image-whithout-having-cue-file-in-linux/)
- [Index» Multimedia and Games» [SOLVED] Mixed CD imaging : how to create BIN/CUE ?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=430973)

Comment: Thank you @sim, for that prompt and complete answer. From the date I am sure, now, that it was created when I was attempting to download an up to date version of Linux. I gave up and bought the DVD. I will remember your very useful "Peeking inside" instructions, but, for now I can just safely remove it.

Comment: If you ever have a pair of `.bin` and `.toc` files (from `cdrdao`) and cannot convert it to `.cue` using `toc2cue` (e.g. because of sub-channel data) you can try to convert it to `.iso` using [raw2iso](https://github.com/not-a-user/raw2iso).